# Instantiate Document Class in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

hi need to instantiate document class in as3. I have a main movie which will load load.swf. The document class of load.swf is LoadedMovie. i use this code :

```
public function Main()
    {
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("load.swf");
        loader=new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);
        loader.load(url);
    }
    function finishLoading(e:Event)
    {
        var sn:LoadedMovie=new LoadedMovie();
        addChild(sn);

    }
```

it's added the movieclip and but my framescripts were not working. i have stop at last frame.
Is it any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Loader will contain an instance of your loaded swf's document class once it's loaded. Simply addChild the loader and you're in business.

```
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("load.swf");
loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);
loader.load(url);
addChild(loader);
```

Instanciating from a loaded swf is slightly more complicated, you have to deal with application domains and such.